# Adding a class to <footer> element when it is visible (in viewport)

Tags: javascript, css, animate.css

css on my website but I would like the animation to start only when the element appears on the page.

I have something like this:

HTML

```
<footer id="footer" class="animate__animated">
    <div class="footer-all">
        <img src="img/logo-hero@2x.png" alt="" class="logo-footer">
        <p class="copyright">CASA DI AMICI C 2020 All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS spec:
After installing Animate.css, add the class animate__animated to an element, along with any of the animation names. Name of animation: animate__fadeIn

JS

```
let footer = document.getElementById("footer");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

    footer.classList.add('animate__fadeIn'); 
});
```

but "scroll" doesn't work, I try load but still doesn't work.
please help me with this

Comment: This is going to be a lot to chew for you I'm sure -- it was for me -- but there's a thing called the Intersection Observer api which allows you to register callbacks when an element is coming into view

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: It's not exactly convenient from what I remember, but it does the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by TKoL you can look into the Intersection Observer API.
But if you want an easier solution, i created this [example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/JjKqJYd)

```
function isInView(el) {
   let box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
   return box.top < window.innerHeight && box.bottom >= 0;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var footer = document.getElementById("footer");
  var visible = isInView(footer);
    if(visible) {
      footer.classList.add("animate__fadeIn");
    } else {
      footer.classList.remove("animate__fadeIn");
    }
});
```

The `isInView` function was found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57279138/3232058)

Answer (score 0):

I find something like this, using jQuery http://www.web2feel.com/freeby/scroll-effects/index5.html